# Create a "smooth" filled plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
value <- c(0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.1)
emotie <- c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
period <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)

df_test <- data.frame(value, emotie, period)
```

And - using ggplot - I create the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_test) + aes(x=factor(period), fill=factor(emotie))+geom_bar(position="fill")
```

This works, however I would like to create a better - and more smooth looking graph like this.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I should change to create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want mapped to the y axis. I assumed the `value` column. Using `geom_area`:

```
ggplot(df_test, aes(x = period, y = value, fill = factor(emotie))) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]